# How to direct email hyperlink to Outlook/Office 10

Tags: windows-10, firefox, email, microsoft-outlook-2010, default-settings

I've been asking Windows 10's Ask me anything and searching without much luck. I am using Firefox, and when presented with an email hyperlink, a box pops up asking me to use an email client I don't want to use, Outlook 2016 and Mail are two of the offerings. However, I cannot direct the settings to Outlook 2010.

I have looked through Default Programs, and cannot figure out how to add Outlook 2010 in that list. I don't want override Mail, and I don't want to use Outlook 2016. Any pointers would be very appreciated.

Comment: You are not given an option to select which program to use?  What has happen is that Outlook 2016 was installed 2010 so, by default, that's the version of Outlook that will be discovered.  You can also change the default program, and select Outlook 2010, instead of the current chosen program.

Comment: @Ramhound My problem though is how to change the default program. I could not find email in that list.

Comment: Is Outlook 2010 actually installed? If so, why do you also have Outlook 2016 installed? If you don't want to use Outlook 2016, why not uninstall it (and then perform a repair/reinstall of 2010)?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus - Find the default program listed as `Mail`/`Outlook 2016`

Comment: I did. I want to find Outlook 2010, and add that to the programs list.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by uninstalling a stub version of Office 365, which came with the Windows 10 installation, and then running an install/repair of Office 2010. Once I did that, although the Icon says email is Outlook 2016 in Control Panel --> , its describing text says Office 2010. So, that fixes my hyperlink problem.

I will enter a new post to ask how to add to the default programs list, even if that is not possible.