# Is it possible to add a properly installed program to Default Programs?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2010, office365, microsoft-office-2010

This question is related to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1168490/how-to-direct-email-hyperlink-to-outlook-office-10/1168900#1168900).

Is it possible to add a properly installed program to Control Panel -> Default Programs, and, if so, how is this done?

I have searched and looked around, but cannot find a way to do this. I fixed the problem stated in the other post, but not the way I wanted to. I would much rather have been able to See Outlook 2010 in Default programs. Office 2010 appears there, but not the individual Office components.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, have you considered doing a clean install of Windows 10 on that machine?  That would eliminate some of the "bloat" related to pre-installed programs and trial versions of applications.  Once you were back and up and running, you could install Office 2010 and have confidence that Outlook 2010 would afford you the opportunity to select it as a default program.

Comment: @Run5k It was a clean install. The laptop is new. It came with Windows 7 and a Windows 10  upgrade package. Office 2010 works fine now.

Comment: I think that you and I may have a different interpretation of what constitutes a clean install.  The laptop may be new, but within the previous question you emphasized that it had *"a stub version of Office 365, which came with the Windows 10 installation."*  As a result, that isn't truly a clean install of Windows 10.  I got home a little while ago and checked my old laptop that has a clean install of Windows 10 x86 with Office 2010 installed.  Outlook 2010 appears as an option within Settings > System > Default Apps > Email, as well as the legacy Set Default Programs interface.

Comment: It has been several days, and I believe that the bottom line is this:  there isn't really a graceful way to do this, primarily because your new laptop arrived with trial versions of various applications.  If you still want to do this, you would need to [use Microsoft's `RefreshWindowsTool.exe` tool to perform a clean install of Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1150268/how-to-completely-delete-programs-that-came-with-my-computer/1150278#1150278), followed by a fresh install of Office 2010.  Just something to consider.

Comment: Thanks. The Outlook 2016 icon is just that, an icon. Using that calls Outlook 2010.